# How to find a string in a sqlite3 table?

Tags: sqlite, shell

Is there a pure sqlite request to find a string in a database ?

With a bit of shell, I can extract the schemas from the tables:

```
for i in *sqlite; 
   do sqlite3 $i ".tables"
   | grep -Eoh "[^ ]+" 
   | while read t; do 
          echo -n "$i:$t  ";
          sqlite3 $i '.schema "'"$t"'"';
   done;
echo;
done
```

Then I could find which column has the type TEXT, and make a request.

But is there a pure SQL way to do this in a terminal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; To dump a sqlite db to a file called `dump.sql`

> sqlite3 some.db .dump > dump.sql

SQLite is designed as an embedded database and therefore does have only extremely basic programming capabilities (it has triggers, but no control logic like `if` or loops).
So it is not possible to do anything dynamic in SQL – the result of [`PRAGMA table_info`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) cannot be directly used in SQL queries.

A very quick and dirty way to search everywhere in a database is to show all contents with `.dump` and then just `grep` that. However, this isn't actually quick because searching indexed columns would be faster in SQL.